# How smart is std::max_element()?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Suppose I have an `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int> v;
[v is initialized]
```

and I want to get the maximum element of `v`. There is an algorithm for doing that:

```
int max_value = *std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
```

So far, so good.

Now, suppose that `v` contains 10,000,000 elements, and its 10th element is equal to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`. Is `std::max_element()` going to (unnecessarily) examine the 9,999,990 last elements of `v`, or is it going to recognize that there cannot be elements larger than `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, and thus stop after the 10th element?

Comment: I doubt the standard says anything about this, but a good implementation could do this.

Comment: I would say that "how smart is it" is a quality of implementation issue. It can be smart or stupid, but as long as it satisfies the contract, you cannot know.

Comment: This won't be a smart thing to do. Such an optimization can hardly be done at zero cost,  and this is an optimization for a rare and non-typical use case.

Comment: make a vector of 100 element, put `numeric_limits<int>::max()` at the end and then compute the time of this algorithm on both vectors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't speak for all implementations, but libc++'s implementation of `max_element` does not do that.

There's a couple problems with the idea:

- The assumption that there exists a specialization of `numeric_limits` for the type of the elements of the sequence. (`max_element` works on anything that can be ordered.) This could be worked around with some template meta-programming.
- There's a version of `max_element` that takes a comparison predicate, not just `operator <`. What's the max value in that case?
- This would require that the type in the sequence be "equality-comparable", not just "less than comparable".
- (Probably the most important) This would introduce a test inside the loop that enumerates the elements of the sequence, thereby slowing the algorithm down for everyone else.